# How do I apply a function with multiple inputs into a data frame using apply?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a cell from a date range (Jan 1- Dec 31, 2021) to just the year with a created function right. I am getting an invalid syntax. Please help

```
def right (s, amount):
    return s[-amount:]

df["Campaign"].apply(right(df["Campaign"], 4), index = 1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I'm voting to close the question because the cause of the problem was an obvious syntax error (missing close-bracket on `df["Campaign"`). In the future, you need to make a [mre] to catch mistakes like this. But also, if you're using Pandas, that's not how you apply a function over a column. Please read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). If you still need help, you can ask a new question after fixing the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `args`

```
df["Campaign"] = df["Campaign"].apply(right, args=(4,), index = 1)
```

the [relevant docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the closing square bracket after the second `Campaign`

```py
df["Campaign"].apply(right(df["Campaign"], 4), index = 1)
```